# Sorting array/object/hash that is populating Chrome Listbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting

I have a listbox that is populating a listbox on my page. The javascript hash that populates it looks alot like this:

```
wiget_cont = ({"39":{"name":"astronaut","id":"39","weight":"189"},
               "37":{"name":"corgi","id":"37","weight":"10"},
               "49":{"name":"zoologist","id":"49","weight":"313"}});
```

In ie and firefox, the listbox populates based off of the alphabetical order of the value of the name key. Of course, chrome sorts off of the numeric key, so my listbox populates all ass-backwards.

I have tried to take the second part of the hash out (as in all of the objects beginning with "name"). The id is obviously used in both the key and the hash. My thinking was to feed an object array with all of the value objects, then sort off of the name. Then create a new hash using the id from that object array as the key, and that array as the value (hopefully this makes some sense). Is this the best way to do this? Because of the framework and existing code, I must use this structure, in and out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array, then sort by the names and iterate over it after

```
var wiget_cont = ({"39":{"name":"astronaut","id":"39","weight":"189"},
               "37":{"name":"corgi","id":"37","weight":"10"},
               "49":{"name":"zoologist","id":"49","weight":"313"}});

var keys = Object.keys(wiget_cont).sort(function (a, b) {return wiget_cont[a].name>wiget_cont[b].name;}),
    i = 0;

for (;i<keys.length;++i) { /* wiget_cont[keys[i]] ... */ }
```

If you don't want to use `>` for string comparison, take a look at [`.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).